# How to pull a type of item from a list view

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

More specificly I want to be able to gather the Labels I have in my ListView's Item template into a list.

This was my latest attempt at it and sadly I am still falling short.

```
foreach (Label lbl in ListView.Items.Where(r => r.ItemType == Label))
```

This is my ASP Control:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" Visible="false" ItemPlaceholderID="phItem"
    OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phItem" runat="server" />
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblChecklist" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCompliant" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblNonCompliant" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblNotApplicable" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblNotComplete" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        There are not results that match your input paramaters.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I've been looking to pull the Labels and now when I look at ListView1.Items during runtime I find the ListView1.Items.Count = 0.

I can pull the Labels individually by their name but I want to pull them so I can get out of hardcoding it.

Comment: If `ListView1.Items.Count == 0` then that means you haven't databound anything to `ListView1`. I updated my answer below and that code will return a list of all the labels in each ItemTemplate that is created when data is bound to the control. Did you give that sample code a shot? Also, remember that `ListView1.Items` refers to the bound templates. It is a list of `ListViewDataItem`, not controls in those templates.

Answer (score 1):

I think the LINQ statement you want is something like:

```
var myLabels = listView1.Items
    .Where(i => i.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    .Select(a => a.FindControl("myLabel"));
```

You want to use `FindControl` on each item to get to the `Label` control you added in the `ItemTemplate`. Remember that `Items` is just a list of `ListViewDataItems`, so you won't be able to select the labels right out of it, even if they are the only thing in the template.

Here's a full working example I threw together.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListView ID="listView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="myLabel" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" /><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:Button ID="btnGatherLabels" Text="Gather Labels" OnClick="btnGatherLabels_Click" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var myItems = new[] { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
            listView1.DataSource = myItems;
            listView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public void btnGatherLabels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myLabels = listView1.Items
                        .Where(i => i.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
                        .Select(a => a.FindControl("myLabel"));
        foreach(Label myLabel in myLabels)
            Response.Write(string.Concat(myLabel.Text, "<br />"));
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT**
Building off my earlier example, let's say the `ItemTemplate` has multiple labels:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="myLabel1" Text="Label Here:" runat="server" /> 
    <asp:Label ID="myLabel2" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" /> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="filler" runat="server" /><br />
</ItemTemplate>
```

The following code will bring back and display the text for each label in each template:

```
public void btnGatherLabels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myLabelCols = listView1.Items
        .Where(i => i.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        .Select(a => 
            a.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                .Where(b => b.GetType().Equals(typeof(Label)))
        );
    foreach (var myLabels in myLabelCols)
        foreach (Label myLabel in myLabels)
            Response.Write(string.Concat(myLabel.Text, "<br />"));
}
```

I'm not sure how you need to use this data, so I did not join them together in one list. Each element in the `myLabelCols` contains a list of all of the labels in that template.

Comment: Ah, this means that for this type of collection my statement would be the wrong approach, I'll delete it.

Comment: I'm not looking for a single item. That would be easy enough. I am looking for a group of them.

Comment: @Hazior: My example assumes that you have one Label in each ItemTemplate, and it brings back all of those in a list. Are you trying to get multiple labels from one ItemTemplate? Do you know all of the IDs? I'd be happy to help, but could you update the question to be more specific about what you are looking for?

Comment: @Hazior Check my update, is that more like what you're looking for?